# Como manipular posição do Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

Preciso comparar todos os elementos de uma lista 2 a 2 estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

Lista: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comparação: 1 e 2, 1 e 3, 1 e 4, 2 e 1, 2 e 3...

Estou utilizando da seguinte maneira:

```
    Iterator<Policie> p1Iterator = setOfPolicies.iterator();
    Iterator<Policie> p2Iterator;

    while(p1Iterator.hasNext()) {
        p1 = p1Iterator.next();
        count++;
        p2Iterator = setOfPolicies.iterator();

        while(p2Iterator.hasNext()) {
            p2 = p2Iterator.next();
        }
   }
```

O que eu queria parar de fazer, é comparar por exemplo: 1 e 2 & 2 e 1. Já que dá no mesmo pra mim. Então já que eu comparo o primeiro com todos os outros, o segundo com todos os outros... Na segunda vez por exemplo, eu compararia o segundo com todos a frente dele, o terceiro com todos a frente dele, e assim por diante. O problema é que não consigo manipular as posições com o iterator, o que eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa ser necessariamente iteradores?

Você poderia converter para uma lista e assim interagir com as posições da lista.

Você pode usar a biblioteca [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.util.Iterator%29): (melhor performance)

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

List<Policie> policies = Lists.newArrayList(p1Iterator);
```

Ou a biblioteca do [java mesmo](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils;

List<Policie> policies = IteratorUtils.toList(p1Iterator);
```

Ou deve ser obrigatoriamente com iteradores? Usando iteradores vai dar um pouco mais de trabalho.

Precisa que poste a lógica de comparação também?

Comment: Não necessita ser com Iterator não, eu não sabia desse método. Acho que assim pode resolver, vou tentar aqui. Valeu.